# Incredible 4G LTE: Things I need to do after getting s-off

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, s-off

I went through the tutorial found [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2214653) and was able to unlock the bootloader, get s-off, get CWM installed, and superuser. Here are the questions I am having now.

1. Should I relock the bootloader after getting s-off? Will that prevent me from doing anything?
2. In that tutorial under the facepalm instructions, do I need to do step 7 if I already got s-off using facepalm?
3. How can I remove *** TAMPERED *** from the bootloader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I relock the bootloader after getting s-off? Will that prevent
>   me from doing anything?

No. You can't flash unsigned ROM nor alter ROM (e.g. get permanent root). [Source](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/20961/5342).

> In that tutorial under the facepalm instructions, do I need to do step
>   7 if I already got s-off using facepalm?

Yes. It is needed so you can flash the `/boot` partition from recovery. The stock HBOOT blocks access while in recovery. [Source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=44599120&postcount=64).

> How can I remove * TAMPERED * from the bootloader?

**UPDATE 2013-08-16:** From OP: After following the steps he mentioned in the guide, `TAMPERED is gone and has been replaced with the -- DirtyRacun -- label. There also is nothing that says UNLOCKED anymore`.

Comment: Awesome thanks a bunch! So for the directions on step 7 though. All I need to do is the steps on the right hand side of the page? I dont need to do all of that stuff down the middle right because thats mostly for getting s-off?

Comment: @Metropolis Yeah, right side only. :)

Comment: Okay heres the deal. I did the HBOOT flash, now the `TAMPERED` is gone and has been replaced with the `-- DirtyRacun --` label. There also is nothing that says UNLOCKED anymore. So I guess if I ever needed to try and get back to stock, I would first need to flash a stock HBOOT and then relock and get s-on right?

Comment: @Metropolis When you flash a stock ROM, you usually lose root, but the bootloader stays unlocked (for Samsung Galaxy S4 anyway). So yes, I suppose you need to do what you just mentioned. You can also Ask another question just to be sure. I'm not familiar with HTC.